# Error when trying to echo values from a data

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I'm getting an error when trying to call for data using echo.

```
{
  "prefix": "_country-",
  "countries": [
    {
      "code": "al",
      "name": "Albania",
      "cities": {
        "prefix": "_city-",
        "options": [
          {
            "code": "durres"
          },
          {
            "code": "tirana"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "dz",
      "name": "Algeria",
      "cities": {
        "prefix": "_city-",
        "options": [
          {
            "code": "algiers"
          },
          {
            "code": "oran"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My goal is to get those data above and expect it to loop until its last data using this code:

```
`foreach($countryarr1['countries'] as $countkey1 => $countname1){ ?> <br><br> <?php 
  foreach($countname1['cities'] as $cntrykey2 => $cntrys){
    foreach($cntrys['options'] as $optionskey1 => $optionsarr1){
      var_dump($optionsarr1);
    }
  }
}`
```

It returns this error

```
'Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\countries.php:25 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\homepage\countries.php on line 25'
```

Here is the line 25

[Error on line 25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4r9.png)

Am I missing something? By the way I'm working on a proxy dashboard for a website.

Here's proof that when I only had 2 arrays it had no problems:

[foreach for 2 arrays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZosg.png)

[output with no errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y4nh.png)

Now when I add another foreach on the 3rd array and so forth, there's the error. Here it is.

[foreach for 3rd array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L19WZ.png)

And the error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpGdt.png)

Comment: I had no problems when doing this on 2 arrays, now I'm at 4 arrays I really don't know what am I missing out. Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? The given code does not contain a line 25, so it's pretty hard to see why it fails

Comment: My bad, here is the line 25 https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4r9.png

Answer (score 0):

Your are using foreach on object **cities**. Either make **cities** array or access **cities** directly.

```
$countname1['cities'] OR $countname1.cities
```

Comment: My apologies forgot to add where line 25 is, here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c4r9.png

Comment: There you may check my edited question, thank you!